# How can I set an AWS EC2 instance's name tag from the instance itself without the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I know how to get meta data and instance tags using curl from an instance, but am I able to set a tag (specifically the name) without using AWS CLI?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the AWS CLI? Or do you have another programming language as a preference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLI is the easiest option, but you can use any of the AWS client libraries - c#, node, python etc or set it manually in the console - but one way or another you need to make a call to the AWS API. You can probably use Curl/Invoke-WebRequest to call the API if you really wanted. You also need to give the instance permission to call the tagging API - this is easiest done with an instance profile.

See this link for example using Curl: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTags.html